# What do I put as the the application context in the given code below (Android app)

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-context, audiorecord

I am creating a class to request permission to use the android AudioRecord feature.

This class is separate from the main activity class. This class is named RecordAudioPermission and the relevant code is listed at the bottom. The problem I am having is that I do not know what to put as the context in the relevant method arguments. I have tried all the usual solutions like putting 'this', `Activity.getContext()`, `RecordAudioPermission.getContext()` etc. but they do not seem to work.

To make the problem code clearer, I have highlighted it with arrows >>[code]<< in the codeblock.

```
public class RecordAudioPermission {

    android.media.AudioRecord RecordAudio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100, CHANNEL_IN_MONO, ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100, CHANNEL_IN_MONO, ENCODING_PCM_16BIT));


    int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;


    private void RecordAudioPermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Pitchpipe.getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Pitchpipe.getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Pitchpipe.getContext(), "Please grant permissions to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Give user option to still opt-in the permissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(>>Pitchpipe.getContext()<<, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

            }

            else {
                // Show user dialog to grant permission to record audio
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(>>Pitchpipe.getContext()<<, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
            }
        }

        //If permission is granted, then go ahead recording audio

        else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Pitchpipe.getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Go ahead with recording audio now
            RecordAudio.startRecording();

        }   

    }

}
```

The most recent solution I have tried (which work for some, but not all, of the methods) is to create a separate class with the same name as my app (Pitchpipe) that gets the context for me.

```
public class Pitchpipe extends Application {
    private static Pitchpipe instance;

    public static Pitchpipe getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
        // or return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

and adding this to the  tag in the android manifest:

```
android:name="com.example.remyryszkowski.pitchpipe.Pitchpipe"
```

and then putting

```
Pitchpipe.getContext()
```

for the context.

Once I get this seemingly simple thing done my guitar tuner app will be (in theory) complete, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am very new to Java, Android and coding in general and I have been learning while I make my first app for about 3 months now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you have to create a constructor that receives a parameter of type Context and store it in a private variable. You'll always need a context to check application permissions or request them as, per documentation:

```
/**
 * Interface to global information about an application environment.  This is
 * an abstract class whose implementation is provided by
 * the Android system.  It
 * allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as
 * up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities,
 * broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.
 */
public abstract class Context {
···
}
```

In [Android API Reference Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

So, you'll need to have your class like this:

```
public class RecordAudioPermission {

    private Context mContext;
    android.media.AudioRecord RecordAudio = ···;


    int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

    public RecordAudioPermission(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void RequestRecordAudioPermission() {
         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Pitchpipe.getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(>>this.mContext<<, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
                Toast.makeText(>>this.mContext<<, "Please grant permissions to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Give user option to still opt-in the permissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(>>this.mContext<<, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

            } else {
                // Show user dialog to grant permission to record audio
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(>>this.mContext<<, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
            }
        }
        ···
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

**NOTE**
The method's ActivityCompat.requestPermissions argument is of type **Activity**, thus it will give an error if you try to pass another type. 
To use the previous decribed class you'll have to proceed like this inside your Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ···

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    ···

    RecordAudioPermission mRecordAudioPermission = new RecordAudioPermission(this);

     mRecordAudioPermission.requestRecordAudioPermission();

    ···
    }

    ···
}
```

Another way to implement you RecordAudioPermission class is using a static method where you can pass the context and execute the permisson check/request:

```
public class RecordAudioPermission {


    android.media.AudioRecord RecordAudio = ···;


    int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

    public static void requestRecordAudioPermission(Context mContext) {
         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(>>mContext<<, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(>>mContext<<, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
                Toast.makeText(>>mContext<<, "Please grant permissions to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Give user option to still opt-in the permissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(>>mContext<<, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

            } else {
                // Show user dialog to grant permission to record audio
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(>>mContext<<, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
            }
        }
        ···
    }
}
```

And inside your Activity class is a bit simple:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ···

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    ···

    RecordAudioPermission.requestRecordAudioPermission(this); //§

    ···
    }

    ···
}
```

**§** ***this*** will be your Activity, meaning your Context object that is needed to show a Toast message and to perform permissions requests.